# Check All Checkboxes based on Div Id and Class using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to check all checkboxes based on Div ID and Checkbox Class. All checkboxes in different divs have the same class. I want to check all checkboxes on button click which is in that particular div. I don't want to use input[type='checkbox'] like below. I want to use only Class Name. Can I do this ?

```
 $('div#'+Id+' input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {            
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
```

Below is my code.

```
<div id="div1">
<input type="button" id="btnDiv1" value="Select All" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />Mark
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />Frank
</div>

<div id="div2">
<input type="button" id="btnDiv2" value="Select All" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />John
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />Travis
<input type="checkbox" class="check" /> Matt
</div>

<div id="div3">
<input type="button" id="btnDiv3" value="Select All" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />Lee
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />Charles
</div>
```

Comment: your jquery code is not clear..can u provide a jsfiddle of your code..?

Comment: You want to check all of them, based on what conditions?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar based on select All button click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call directly 'prop()' method with your class selector like this:

```
$('div#'+Id+' input.check').prop('checked', true);
```

EDIT:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('.check').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use input check. I mentioned that clearly in my question.

Comment: Sorry you are edit your post after my answer ... :/ But can you explain why you don't want use checkbox selector? :O

Comment: Its the requirement to do with the class Name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
   $(this).find('input:not([type=button])').prop('checked',true);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nyg6kqv0/)

Comment: I clearly mentioned in the question to use class and dont use input type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the checkbox elements within a group when clicking the 'Select All' button, you could give the 'Select All' elements a common class name and then attach a `click` event listener.

You could either use `.nextAll()` to select all the succeeding `.check` elements:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gokrn06p/)

```
$('.select-all').on('click', function () {
    $(this).nextAll('.check').prop('checked', true);
});
```

---

..or you could select the closest `div` ancestor, and then select all the `.check` elements within it:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/416k141n/)

```
$('.select-all').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.check').prop('checked', true);
});
```

---

If you want to select the elements based on the number within the clicked 'Select All' button's `id`, you could use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tsb2nbL/)

```
$('.select-all').on('click', function () {
    $('#div' + this.id.replace(/\D/g, '') +' .check').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: this gives typeError -  Cannot read property 'on' of null. Is there another way to accomplish this?